# Can I use `tf.nn.dropout` to implement DropConnect?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I (think) that I grasp the basics of DropOut and the [use of the TensorFlow API in implementing it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34597667/656912). But the normalization that's linked to the dropout probability in `tf.nn.dropout` seems not to be a part of [DropConnect](http://cs.nyu.edu/%7Ewanli/dropc/). Is that correct? If so, does normalizing do any "harm" or can I simply apply `tf.nn.dropout` to my weights to implement DropConnect?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Answer

Yes, you can use **tf.nn.dropout** to do **DropConnect**, just use **tf.nn.dropout** to wrap your weight matrix instead of your post matrix multiplication.  You can then *undo* the weight change by multiplying by the dropout like so

```
dropConnect = tf.nn.dropout( m1, keep_prob ) * keep_prob
```

## Code Example

Here is a code example that calculates the **XOR** function using drop connect.  I've also commented out the code that does dropout that you can sub in and compare the output.

```
### imports
import tensorflow as tf

### constant data
x  = [[0.,0.],[1.,1.],[1.,0.],[0.,1.]]
y_ = [[1.,0.],[1.,0.],[0.,1.],[0.,1.]]

### induction

# Layer 0 = the x2 inputs
x0 = tf.constant( x  , dtype=tf.float32 )
y0 = tf.constant( y_ , dtype=tf.float32 )

keep_prob = tf.placeholder( dtype=tf.float32 )

# Layer 1 = the 2x12 hidden sigmoid
m1 = tf.Variable( tf.random_uniform( [2,12] , minval=0.1 , maxval=0.9 , dtype=tf.float32  ))
b1 = tf.Variable( tf.random_uniform( [12]   , minval=0.1 , maxval=0.9 , dtype=tf.float32  ))


########## DROP CONNECT
# - use this to preform "DropConnect" flavor of dropout
dropConnect = tf.nn.dropout( m1, keep_prob ) * keep_prob
h1 = tf.sigmoid( tf.matmul( x0, dropConnect ) + b1 ) 

########## DROP OUT
# - uncomment this to use "regular" dropout
#h1 = tf.nn.dropout( tf.sigmoid( tf.matmul( x0,m1 ) + b1 ) , keep_prob )


# Layer 2 = the 12x2 softmax output
m2 = tf.Variable( tf.random_uniform( [12,2] , minval=0.1 , maxval=0.9 , dtype=tf.float32  ))
b2 = tf.Variable( tf.random_uniform( [2]   , minval=0.1 , maxval=0.9 , dtype=tf.float32  ))
y_out = tf.nn.softmax( tf.matmul( h1,m2 ) + b2 )


# loss : sum of the squares of y0 - y_out
loss = tf.reduce_sum( tf.square( y0 - y_out ) )

# training step : discovered learning rate of 1e-2 through experimentation
train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-2).minimize(loss)

### training
# run 5000 times using all the X and Y
# print out the loss and any other interesting info
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run( tf.initialize_all_variables() )
  print "\nloss"
  for step in range(5000) :
    sess.run(train,feed_dict={keep_prob:0.5})
    if (step + 1) % 100 == 0 :
      print sess.run(loss,feed_dict={keep_prob:1.})


  results = sess.run([m1,b1,m2,b2,y_out,loss],feed_dict={keep_prob:1.})
  labels  = "m1,b1,m2,b2,y_out,loss".split(",")
  for label,result in zip(*(labels,results)) :
    print ""
    print label
    print result

print ""
```

## Output

Both flavors are able to correctly separate the input into the correct output

```
y_out
[[  7.05891490e-01   2.94108540e-01]
 [  9.99605477e-01   3.94574134e-04]
 [  4.99370173e-02   9.50062990e-01]
 [  4.39682379e-02   9.56031740e-01]]
```

Here you can see the output from dropConnect was able to correctly classify **Y** as true,true,false,false.

Comment: And for convolutional layers: I assume DropConnect applies, in the same way, to the kernel weights, in place of Dropout's application before/after ([I'm never clear which(https://stackoverflow.com/q/37573674/656912)) pooling. Correct?

Comment: Yes, you can use it to dropconnect any weight.  The trick is to wrap the weight and not the post processing.  For convolution, you'll have a weight matrix just like the above code and you'd wrap it in just the same way.  Cheers.

Comment: As for pooling, applying dropout after pooling is conceptually different.  Conceptually I'd think of dropout on pooling more akin to "best of subset" instead of "best of set"

Comment: I'd love some better answers (or opinions) for my [related question](stackoverflow.com/q/37573674/656912) on that point.

Comment: The [Regularization of Neural Networks using DropConnect](https://cs.nyu.edu/~wanli/dropc/dropc.pdf) paper says "Additionally, the biases are also masked out during training" - does this mean that the code above should have applied `tf.nn.dropout(b1, keep_prob)*keep_prob` to `b1` ?

Comment: oh, that's an interesting question.  It is worth a test, or at least a thought experiment.  As a thought experiment I'd say that the bias acts to "white balance" the embedding space where as dropConnect acts to make layer-to-layer connections act redundantly, so my gut would say that using dropConnect on a bias is misguided.  But, it is worth a test.  I don't see anything in that paper which empirically tests with and without.  It's more like they are saying what they did - just so you know.